# Storybook description field is missing in canvas tab

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

I used `npx storybook init` command to install storybook.

When I ran storybook, I found one strange point.

The `description` and `default` field exist in docs tab, but not in the canvas tab.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

### Docs tab

[image]

### Canvas tab

[image]

### versions

- nextjs: 12.1.6
- storybook: 6.5.4

### How to reproduce

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest --ts
npx npx storybook init
npm install
npm run storybook
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.storybook/preview.js` file, add the following:

```
export const parameters = {
  controls: {
    expanded: true
  }
}
```

Here's the documentation: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#show-full-documentation-for-each-property